# How to move file from Windows to Linux subsystem?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a tar.gz file downloaded in Windows and I want to move it to the linux subsystem directory. Is it safe to directly paste my files in the `lxss` folder?. Is it possible to do it safely?

System: Windows 10 along with Ubuntu subsystem terminal

- I am aware that I can access Windows directories from linux subsystem terminal via `/mnt/c`
- I am also aware that editing files in linux subsystem directories using windows tools is dangerous

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate of the above mentioned question

Comment: The duplicate tells you how to transfer files if you read the first answer. I really do not think a unique question for each file type is realistic

Comment: I read both answers, and I don't see any general solution to this issue, so it would seem not to be a duplicate.

Comment: It's not a duplicate and here is the answer: https://ridicurious.com/2018/10/18/2-ways-to-copy-files-from-windows-10-to-windows-sub-system-for-linux/